# How to use RunApp function more efficiently for changing Pages

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am creating an Android App with Landing Screen loading for five seconds. I am using RunApp function to call Landing Page and The landing page will call Homepage app after Five seconds. Is this an Efficient way to do this type of work.

I tried using navigation feature but when I press the back button it returns to landing Page.

This is used to call my landing Home

```
import './pages/landing.dart';


void main() {

    runApp(LandingHome(),
    ); 

}
```

On Landing.dart

```
import 'package:neptools/pages/homepage.dart';


class LandingHome extends StatefulWidget{
 @override
_LandingHomeState createState() => _LandingHomeState();
}

class _LandingHomeState extends State<LandingHome>{
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds:5),() => runApp(HomePage()), );
  }
```

Rest is UI elements for Landing Home

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
//Other UI Elements
```

Everything Is Okay. I wanted to know how efficient is this method. I thought this will consume more memory as the app landingHome Might Run in Background

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling basically your root function again, I think it's better if you create named routes.

After the 5 seconds delay you can push to the particular named route.

This makes your root function to be executed only once and less error prone

[Named Routes Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes)

You can use packages to make your life easier creating named routes
[Compassion](https://pub.dev/packages/compassion)

Also why are you trying to do that? Your app also has a splashscreen which is shown till the required resources are loaded in the memory and it's speed it depends upon the hardware. In lower end devices assuming a 3 seconds + 5 seconds = 8 seconds wait for user after launching the app. I don't think it's a good idea. You should try to avoid it.